# How to stop a new form from using namespace System::Collections

Tags: c++, forms, collections, namespaces, using

If I create a new form called myForm, the top of myForm.h looks like this:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;     //<<<< THIS ONE
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

None of these are even needed, because the wonderful forms designer always fully-qualifies its objects.

The one marked with THIS ONE is particularly annoying because it breaks my build. This is because I use the generic form of IList all over the place - I love it so much that I put it in stdafx.h, like this:

```
using System::Collections::Generic::IList;
```

So then if I want to use myForm from any other file where I happen to use IList, like this:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "ABC.h"
#include "myForm.h"

ABC::ABC()
{
    IList<int>^ myList;
    ...
}
```

then it fails to compile:

```
1>.\ABC.cpp(7) : error C2872: 'IList' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : System::Collections::Generic::IList'
1>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : System::Collections::IList'
1>.\ABC.cpp(7) : error C2872: 'IList' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : System::Collections::Generic::IList'
1>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : System::Collections::IList'
```

**So, how can I stop a new form from adding all these useless and destructive usings?**

Comment: Code them up with notepad.  Seriously though, I'm assuming you're using VS?

Comment: Sorry yep VS2008 and C++/CLI - whoops forgot to add that info :*)

Comment: Why not just strip them out by hand? It isn't like the IDE will go and put the using declaration back in afterwards.

Comment: You're right, and that is what I'm doing at the moment. I just find it a bit tedious and wondered if there was a quick way of removing those usings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default templates that Visual Studio uses by editing the zip files in the ItemTemplates directory for the specific language that you use.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`

is where the C# templates are.  I'm assuming the C++ templates would be in a similar directory but I don't have a VS instance installed with C++ handy.

Comment: VC ones are in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualC\1033  however there are only 4 zipfiles - HelpTest, OrderedTest, SimpleUnitTest and UnitTestWizard. No Form.zip or anything remotely useful :(

Comment: Huh.  Interesting.  Well this directory seems promising:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcprojectitems\Code ... except that the code.vsdir file seems to be pointing to some registry keys... let me follow them...

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/86b9d540-376f-4cb7-bd4f-f401e0fba7b3 seems to be in the right direction.  Not sure if editing the "hfile.h" would solve your issue though.

Comment: You almost got it, I'm gonna accept your answer. I found a file called newform.h and removed the annoying using from it, so now any new forms do not have that in. Thanks! C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\.NET\WinForm\Templates\1033\newform.h

Answer (score 2):

You can modify Form Template of Visual Studio. For further reading, take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry I don't see where it applies to forms - it only seems to talk about projects. Could you explain how to use this method to change the form template?

Comment: Item templates should be located at:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualC\1033"

However it's recommended create your own custom form template, rather than modifying a default one. You can find instructions on how to create your own template right here:
http://www.dev102.com/2008/07/24/visual-studio-item-templates/

Comment: Thanks but in this case I did actually want to modify the default one. Why would you say it's recommended to create a custom one?

Comment: Custom template are stored in My Document folder and can be backed up. It's easier to restore your machine after reinstalling of VS, or sending this template to your colleagues.